# Using PostGIS for the first time, what is the geospatial template?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to implement some location aware/spatial lookup features to my django project.  I have realized that I need to switch over to a PostGIS enabled db rather than just a plain Postgres db, I hope this is right?
I keep reading countless tutorials such as this one https://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/geo-django-quickstart/
which suggests that I need to create a geospatial template before i can actually create or enable a PostGIS db.  See the code below:

```
POSTGIS_SQL_PATH=`pg_config --sharedir`/contrib/postgis-1.5
# Creating the template spatial database.
sudo -u postgres createdb -E UTF8 template_postgis
sudo -u postgres createlang -d template_postgis plpgsql # Adding PLPGSQL language support.
# Allows non-superusers the ability to create from this template
sudo -u postgres psql -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='true' WHERE datname='template_postgis';"
# Loading the PostGIS SQL routines
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/spatial_ref_sys.sql
# Enabling users to alter spatial tables.
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "GRANT ALL ON geography_columns TO PUBLIC;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "GRANT ALL ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;"
```

But than I read other tutorials that say I can simply create a new Postgresql db or take my existing one and do:

```
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;"
```

Which one is it?  am I even on the right path here?  This PostGIS stuff sounds incredibly confusing.

Comment: I would suggest following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) guide. Create extension is how you register extra packages in Postgres. So, Create extension Postgis basically loads a bunch of functions and types that will allow you to do spatial. If you do this step first, against the db you want to work with, and then do the geodjango setup, you should be fine. I did this myself a few weeks ago and, although I am a very experienced Postgres/Postgis user, I had never used Django before, and it worked first time. Good luck.

Comment: Your link is for 1.5, currently there's a 2.x version that has some major changes.

Comment: @JakubKania, I could only find 1.8 and dev. Perhaps you could put up a link, answer the question? The question about create extension postgis remains, no?

Comment: @JohnBarça, Oh, sorry I meant the OP. His tutorial is for 1.5 and thus why there are diffrences to other tutorials out there. I don't know geodjango, sorry.

Comment: @JakubKania. No worries, I have only used GeoDjango a little, but it works really well, and I had no problem following the setup guide.

Comment: So PostGIS doesn't do spatial lookups out of the box?  I have to apply the extensions?  Also, will I probably not need to use the giant block of code I included above (all the command line sudo stuff)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have PostgreSQL 9.1 (or later) and PostGIS 2.x, definitely try the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` method first, since it is way easier. Only add the other extensions if you need topology and/or TIGER geocoding support (most folks don't).

Templates are are somewhat old fashioned and these instructions can be ignored. Templates were useful before extensions were introduced in 2011. (The blog you posted to was published the same month PostgreSQL 9.1 with extension support was released). Other techniques you may see to enable a PostGIS database are running enabler scripts, but again ignore these if you can.